# Twitter API: How to get user's tweets from a timeframe?

Tags: twitter

I can't quite believe this, but seems there's no way to get tweets from a particular user from a particular timeframe. Is this true? is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Johnny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this listing of Twitter resources for retrieving historical data. It looks like Tweetbird is the top with Searchastic getting good reviews, but it's shutdown now.

http://blog.tweetsmarter.com/twitter-search/10-ways-and-20-features-for-searching-old-tweets/

There is also a site called Snapbird that queries old tweets. They also have an API on Github that circumvents the 10 day search limit. You can of course use any API method to get user tweets.

https://github.com/remy/snapbird

You can also use Twitter's own `since` and `until` operator for timeframes but the capacity of historical data is limited, so it is recommended to use the resources listed instead.

example:

`https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&inc‌​lude_rts=true&screen_name={screen_name}&since:2011-11-01&until:2011-11-06`